# Find path in error logging of Codeginter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have initiated the error logging on my website.

`$config\['log_threshold'\] = 1;`

But since the day I have started it I started getting following logs like -

```
ERROR - 2023-02-09 06:37:50 --> 404 Page Not Found: Assets/js
ERROR - 2023-02-09 06:37:50 --> 404 Page Not Found: Assets/js
ERROR - 2023-02-09 06:37:50 --> 404 Page Not Found: Assets/bootstrap
ERROR - 2023-02-09 06:38:05 --> 404 Page Not Found: Assets/fonts
ERROR - 2023-02-09 06:38:05 --> 404 Page Not Found: Assets/js
ERROR - 2023-02-09 06:38:05 --> 404 Page Not Found: Assets/bootstrap
ERROR - 2023-02-09 06:38:05 --> 404 Page Not Found: Assets/bootstrap
ERROR - 2023-02-09 06:38:05 --> 404 Page Not Found: Assets/js
ERROR - 2023-02-09 06:39:02 --> 404 Page Not Found: Assets/js
ERROR - 2023-02-09 06:39:02 --> 404 Page Not Found: Assets/bootstrap
ERROR - 2023-02-09 06:39:02 --> 404 Page Not Found: Assets/fonts
ERROR - 2023-02-09 06:39:02 --> 404 Page Not Found: Assets/js
ERROR - 2023-02-09 06:39:02 --> 404 Page Not Found: Assets/bootstrap
ERROR - 2023-02-09 06:39:15 --> 404 Page Not Found: Assets/bootstrap
ERROR - 2023-02-09 06:39:15 --> 404 Page Not Found: Assets/js
ERROR - 2023-02-09 06:39:15 --> 404 Page Not Found: Assets/fonts
ERROR - 2023-02-09 06:39:15 --> 404 Page Not Found: Assets/bootstrap
ERROR - 2023-02-09 06:39:15 --> 404 Page Not Found: Assets/js
ERROR - 2023-02-09 06:39:24 --> 404 Page Not Found: Repository/css
```

I have thousands of pages of website and it's really difficult to understand which page is generating these errors. Is there any way I can get a page name which generating these errors.

I have tried changing the threshold value to 2 but that didn't work

Answer (score 0):

1. see the website devtools console log (F12 in Chrome) and you can see which files are not found on the page.
2. see the access.log on the server
3. previously I solved it by creating two arrays in the core file, you may have to refactor the code a bit, but it will be much more understandable

```
$this->data->js = [];
$this->data->css = [];
```

and then I added the required css and js files in the core controllers :

```
$this->data->js[] = 'jquery';
$this->data->js[] = 'https://remote.js/file.js';

$this->data->css[] = 'bootstrap';
$this->data->css[] = 'https://google.fonts/fonts.css';
```

with this solution i can always add a custom js or css (which is only related to this function) file in the controller or class constructor

```
public function add_user() {
    $this->data->js[] = 'users/add_user'; //assets/js/users/add_user.js
}
```

then in the view files wrapper foreach these arrays in the `<head>`

```
<?php
    if(isset($css)) {
        foreach ($css as $key => $value) {
            if (preg_match('/(https?:)?\/\//', $value) === 1) {
                echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' . $value . '" />' . PHP_EOL;
            } else if (file_exists(FCPATH . 'assets/css/' . $value . '.css')) {
                echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' . site_url() . 'assets/css/' . $value . '.css?' . filemtime(FCPATH . 'assets/css/' . $value . '.css') . '" />' . PHP_EOL;
            } else {
                log_message("ERROR", $value . ' css file not found');
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

and after the `</body>` tag

```
<?php
if(isset($js)) {
    foreach ($js as $key => $value) {
        if (preg_match('/(https?:)?\/\//', $value) === 1) {
            echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="' . $value . '"></script>' . PHP_EOL;
        } else if (file_exists(FCPATH . '/assets/js/' . $value .'.js')) {
            echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="' . site_url() .'assets/js/'. $value . '.js?' . filemtime(FCPATH  .'assets/js/'.  $value .'.js' ) . '"></script>' . PHP_EOL;
        } else {
            log_message('ERROR',$value. ' javascript file not found');
        }
    }
}
?>
```